# Gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: react-native

I follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvy8ACbP38I
I have error, **gradlew assembleRelease** ,
how to fix this -->

gradlew : The term 'gradlew' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1

- gradlew assembleRelease
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (gradlew:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVTOf.png)

Comment: Did you install android studio?

Comment: XPowerDev yes bro, I installed

Comment: I think that you are missing the ./ at the start of the command:Try this: ./gradlew assembleRelease

Comment: Do you use windows or mac?

Comment: Yes bro i use windows. I found that issue now. it fixed.  ./gradlew assembleRelease